# How to store UserName and QuizScore of users from LocalStorage into Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, local-storage

I am a beginner at using NodeJs and MongoDB. Please go light on me.
Previously, I only developed the front-end part of a quiz app. Now, I have started to create the back end for it. Previously, I was storing the UserName(Taking input from User at HomePage) in LocalStorage.After the user completes the quiz I would show it on their ScoresPage with their scores at the end.

Now I have both the scores and userName in LocalStorage. I want to store them in my mongoDB Database. I can't access the LocalStorage with the help of NodeJS.How can I store them in my database with the help of NodeJS?

[My LocalStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A93J.png)

Comment: [You can get data from local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). And then loaded data would be requested by `fetch` to node backend server.

Comment: If you want to store data in mongoDB then you need a backend server running. You can run a server with bare node js but using middleware like express js is easy and common.

Comment: @jacobkim I am using ExpressJS. I can't access the local storage I used previously for the client-side from NodeJS. It says `Local storage is undefined`. Help me out if you can!

Comment: So the problem is that from client end local storage can not be got. If you show code of client-side then it would be easier to answer.

Comment: You may try to `console.log(localStorage.getItem('name'))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access localStorage on the server side, you need to grab the values from the localStorage on the client side like this:

```
const userName = localStorage.getItem('name');
const score= localStorage.getItem('mostRecentScore');
```

And then send it to the server inside the request body, let's say your'e using axios on the frontend:

```
const serverPathForStoringData = "https://yourServerUrl/storeData";
axios.put(serverPathForStoringData , {
   userName,
   score
})
.then((response) => {
   //do something with the response in the frontend if you want
   console.log(response)
 }, (error) => {
   console.log(error);
 });
```

and on the server side :

```
router.put("/storeData", (req, res)=>{
    const {userName, score} = req.body;
    // here you can store userName and score inside the database
    res.json({data:"data successfuly stored in DB!"})
   });
```